# Adding multiple foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I am having trouble adding multiple foreign key constraints to this table. I get an error saying

> Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Both id's referenced are primary keys in their respective tables. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE `works_on` (
    `eid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `start_date` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`eid`, `pid`),
    CONSTRAINT `works_on_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eid`)
    REFERENCES `employee` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `works_on_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) 
    REFERENCES `project` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: What database system are you using? MySQL? MS SQL? MariaDb?

Comment: And please, always show us the Complete error message

Comment: Sorry, I am using MariaDB and when I try to run the query, it says "Foreign key is incorrectly formed."

Also, VSCode is saying '.' expected at the start of that 2nd constraint.

Comment: Is this a many:many mapping table?  What's the scenario for needing the `SET` or `CASCADE`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a paradox here - you cannot have a primary key where any of the elements has a null values AND therefore you cannot on delete SET NULL..

You should also be seeing an error message telling you that the primary key is invalid..

Comment: The two foreign keys reference two different primary keys which are auto incremented, and I want it so that if any rows are deleted, the 'eid' / 'pid' referenced for that row is reverted back to null.

Comment: Not revert to NULL, delete the row.  Then use `LEFT JOIN` to get a "NULL".